# kernel appeared in jupyter notebook but not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, virtualenv, jupyter

I am planning to use virtual environment in jupyter notebook through the following steps:

```
conda create -n test python==3.6
conda activate test
ipython kernel install --user --name=test
```

Then i get the following in return:

```
Installed kernelspec test in C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\test
```

which seems to be working when I saw the test kernel appeared in jupyter notebook.

However, when I switch to that kernel, it is actually using my default python enviroment.

I also checked the existing kernels with:

```
λ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  shjh       C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\shjh
  test       C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\test
  python3    C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

It is there but not working ...

Any suggestions how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is causing the problem. But luckily I found a working solution.

First I removed the installed kernel with

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall <kernel name>
```

then added again with ipykernel:

```
conda create -n test python==3.6
conda activate test
(test) λ pip install ipykernel
(test) λ python -m ipykernel install --name test --display-name "some name"
```